# How to get direct Google play store app download link for user?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-developers-console, android-developer-api, applinks

I have uploaded an app to the Google play store which is published successfully and is in production mode. But the problem is if click on the play store app link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weather.check.app then it requires sign-in for the user to install.
Could anyone please tell me how to get a direct user download link where the user doesn't need to sign in to install the app?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a google play link to share/download then you have to sign in with an account to download/install. Otherwise you can generate a signed build for your apk using Android Studio and save that apk file inside a google drive folder and make that folder accessible to all(public) and share the public url for this folder so that users can download and install it without signing up.

Comment: I think the uploader meant the direct Google Play store link. Play store calls the Google Play API (android.clients.google.com) to get the APK download link (this DOES require a valid account AND supported device). There are open-source projects that work with Google Play API, so use that to get your link. Note that you only need a Google account that one time, for the API - the link it returns is to Google's CDN (not their API), pointing directly to the APK file so you can share that link for everyone to download your app. Note that your users still need to enable sideloading to install it.